# Distributing IPA file with App-store signing

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa, in-house-distribution

So I'm not using `enterprise distribution profile` to archive and export my project into IPA file.
I am using a valid distribution certificate though.

On XCode organizer I've made sure that everything is valid by clicking on the `validate` button for my particular archive before `exporting` it using the exact same `distribution certificate` and `distribution provisioning profile`. Also, I've made sure that I checked `App Store` as the method of distribution.

So I assumed everything checked out, then I distributed the IPA through [diawi](http://diawi.com).

This is what I used to distribute my development IPA at the early stage of this project. However, upon opening the diawi link, installation just failed on my device saying "Unable to download" every single time.

Now I'm just wondering is it not at all possible to distribute through diawi if I'm not using `enterprise distribution profile` to build the ipa itself?
Or am I building it the wrong way for the intended purpose?

I'm very new to this whole Apple environment so not sure if I'm understanding the process correctly. I'm developing this from a react native project in case you need to know.

Thanks in advance for any pointers! :D

EDIT:
There seems to be confusion in the answers so far. Just to clarify, I'm **NOT** using `enterprise distribution profile` nor I am using development provisioning profile. So adding UDID to the provisioning profile is not an option. The case I'm asking about is for ipa signed with **app store distribution provisioning profile** which I'm trying to share using diawi. It doesn't seem to be possible to distribute ipa signed this way with diawi based on my research, but I just wanna be extra sure. Sorry for the confusion. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the UDID of downloading device added to the  provisional profile. Login to your apple developer account and check if the device is added or no. If not add that device and then update the  provisional profile by selecting that new UDID. Download the updated profile and the build.

Comment: adding UDID is only for internal and development profiles only though, if ur building with distribution signing there's no option to do so for the distribution provisioning profile I'm pretty sure...

Comment: That is the case when you are using TestFlight and you have already invited your user for testing through apple developer portal. But in your case you are distributing it through Diawi, you need to add the devices on apple developer portal first and then update your provision profile.

Comment: I am aware of that but if you try opening your distribution provisioning profile, not the development one, there's no option to do so. I'm well aware that you can do that with development distribution because you are only allowing registered devices to install your app, but for a more widespread distribution, i.e. apps signed with app store distribution, there is no such option on the developer portal

Comment: There is option. Just go your developer portal, select your distribution provision profile and click edit, down you will see the list of devices. Select any missing ones and generate the provision profile.

Comment: There is, just did it yesterday.

Comment: check out the image I linked there

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it's true that diawi can only distribute **in-house apps** (signed using enterprise program account) and **development** provisioning profile signed apps.

The reason what I'm trying to do is not working (not installing through diawi) is because I'm trying to distribute an app signed with classic apple account's **distribution provisioning profile** instead of **development provisioning profile**
As far as I my googling went yesterday, apps signed with **distribution provisioning** profile under **classic account** is only distributable through app store or test flight.

Let me know if I miss anything.

Comment: Did you find a way @Ray to distribute your app with distribution provisioning profile?